# Как отличить определение, выраженное прилагательным, от сказуемого, выраженного прилагательным

Tags: прилагательные, сказуемые, определения

Всем привет.
Я не совсем улавливаю разницу между прилагательными в качестве определения и сказуемого. Мне бы надежный признак.
Спасибо

P. S.
Пример:

*Глубокое озе­ро.

Наше озе­ро глу­бо­кое*,

в котором слово "глубокое":

- отвечает на один и тот же вопрос;
- выражено в одном и том же роде;
- одним и тем же падежом;
- имеет одно и то же лексическое значение.

Comment: Вы, простите, уверены, что правильно задали вопрос? Если да, то приведите хоть одно предложение, которое вызывает у вас затруднение в плане определения роли (из числа упомянутых) прилагательного. Дело в том, что прилагательное в роли дополнения - случай весьма редкий и специфический, его просто трудно с чем-то спутать, оно выступает в функции существительного и вопрос к нему - не "какой, какого...", а "кто/что, кого/чего".

Comment: Не знаю как ошибся: не дополнение а определение в качестве прилагательного

Comment: Ясно, то есть ваш вопрос на самом деле не из области академических дебрей, а вполне школьный. Голос за закрытие отзываю, как время будет - отвечу, если других добровольцев не найдется.

Answer (score 2):

1. ***Наше озеро глубокое. Наше озеро было глубокое.***

Это предложения.  Предложение – это единица речи, содержащее сообщение (информацию) о предмете.

Озеро – подлежащее, глубокое – сказуемое.
Сказуемое составное именное: связка БЫТЬ + именная часть, выраженная прилагательным.В настоящем времени связка пропущена.

2. ***Глубокое озеро.***  *Глубокое* – определение.

Это словосочетание. У словосочетания, как и  у слова, назывная функция, в отличие от предложения. Словосочетание может быть названием рассказа.

3. Но такое словосочетание может быть и односоставным **назывным (номинативным)** предложением, обозначающим место действия рассказа, например: "***Глубокое Озеро. Сколько тайн скрыто в нем!"***

Здесь ***глубокое*** – также определение, а *озеро* – подлежащее в односоставном предложении без сказуемого.

4. Кроме того, это же сочетание может быть **двусоставным** предложением с инверсией, например:

"***Дна не видно. ГлубОкое озеро***".  Такое же значение имеет предложение с прямым порядком слов: *Озеро глубОкое.*

Здесь ***глубокое*** – именная часть сказуемого.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon